# Setting location of controls in viewDidLoad

Tags: ios, objective-c

I'm trying to initialize the location of a control based on portrait/landscape in viewDidLoad, as below.  It seems that the desired code is firing, but when my application starts the label appears in *neither* location, just the place where it was dropped in IB.

Am I forgetting a step, or does this have to happen somewhere else?

Thanks for any thoughts.

```
int w = self.UILabel_Label.frame.size.width;
int h = self.UILabel_Label.frame.size.height;

m_LabelFrame_Portrait = CGRectMake(10,50, w, h);
m_LabelFrame_Landscape = CGRectMake(600,50, w, h);

//self.UILabel_Label.frame = CGRectMake(200,200, w, h);

if (m_OrientationLayoutMode == OLM_Portrait)
{
    self.UILabel_Label.frame = m_LabelFrame_Portrait;
}
else
{
    self.UILabel_Label.frame = m_LabelFrame_Landscape;
}
```

Comment: Did you check connection the label to the view controller in IB?

Comment: Yeah, I think it's fine because I position the label later (on rotates).  In fact I just added a line to set the label text right after the above code in ViewDidLoad, and it works fine.  Weird.

Comment: Is there some positioning code that kicks in after viewDidLoad?

Comment: viewWillAppear, viewDidAppear...

Comment: Are you using auto layout (you are, if you haven't turned it off, since it's on by default)?

Comment: Interesting, viewDidAppear works, but viewDidLoad and viewWillAppear do not work.  Does that make sense?  In any case, thanks very much.

Comment: @rdelmar, how do I turn that on/off?  I haven't attached any positional "constraints" to the label in IB, if that's what you mean?

Comment: The system adds constraints for you, if you don't do it yourself. There's a check box in the "File Inspector" in the storyboard, that you can uncheck to turn it off. Alternately, you could make any changes in viewDidLoad by changing constraints rather than setting frames.

Comment: @rdelmar, thanks I see the checkbox.  It doesn't seem to make any difference though, and I've never noticed any positional change on rotation (which is the only resize I've worked with really) unless I add a constraint manually, or move it programmatically.  What do the "default" constraints that you mention do?  Just keep it at a constant X and Y relative to the container?

Comment: I'm not sure what the default constraints are, which is why I always explicitly add the ones I want.